# Java Web Application Source Files

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I will start off by saying that I have absolutely no experience developing in Java.  I recently picked up a client that needed some simple updates to their website.  I was originally told that it was a static website.  When I received the files, it was clearly not an static website.

The problem is that I have no idea what to do with these files.  Here is the basic structure of the files broken into two directories (http and java)

http

- contact-us
- css
- images
- includes
- js
- layouts
- etc

java

- build
- lib
- src
- web

From what I can tell, the http directory houses all the html content of the site with a directory structure setup like the structure of the live site.  The java directory contains the following

- java/build - web.xml files
- java/lib - jar files
- java/src - a directory structure with .java class files
- java/web - jsp files

I have apache tomcat running on my local machine and i have downloaded eclipse.  From here though, I have no idea what to do next.

If anyone can suggest how I might move forward or can explain the directory structure, or anything else helpful, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What is that you want achieve? Are you planning to change only the look and feel of existing components?

Comment: Yes, right now the changes I need to make are cosmetic.  However, not knowing how a site like this needs to be built or deployed, or how I need to send the files back, I'm not sure the proper way I should go about these edits.  I was hoping to setup the files locally so I could make the edits and run it locally.

Comment: Has the client shipped a build.xml or a pom.xml file?

Comment: Nope. Neither of those files were sent.

Comment: Maybe you should ask the client about more information on how they build their application? Do they expect you to create an automated build for them as well as part of the contract? There are ways to make this work without an automated build but it would be faster if you just picked up a book on Java EE applications than to wait for someone to write an answer explaining the process.

Comment: The only expectation is that I send them files with the edits back to them.  Do you think I could just edit the html files directly and send that back to them?  With what I have described, do you think these are the hosted files and not the project files?  I still do not know what I'm looking at.

Comment: If the changes are only cosmetic in nature and can be achieved by only changing the html and css files which I assume is your area of expertise, there doesn't seem to be a need to build and deploy the entire application. You could edit just the html/css files and send it back to them.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Java web application from existing sources in Eclipse. Analyse the project from there.